# split 3 values seperated by commas into 3 different pairs

Tags: python, string

I'd like to split 3 values separated by commas

```
a = 'a,b,c'
```

into 3 different pairs:

```
(a,b), (b,c), (a,c)
```

How would I be able to do this on Python?

I have tried

```
n = [(x) for x in a.split(',')]
x = list(zip(n[1::], n[0::2]))
```

I get one pair: `('a', 'b')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the logic is behind grouping these pairs together:

```
(a,b), (b,c), (a,c)
```

However, if you wanted to group each element with every other element you can use this:

```
a = 'a,b,c'
my_list = a.split(',')
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    for j in my_list:
        if i != j:
            new_list.append((i,j))
```

And you will get

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations
a = 'a,b,c'
a = a.split(",")
for group in combinations(a,2):
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using libraries, you can use `combinations` from `itertools`. [Itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

In this case, it would be as simple as:

```
from itertools import combinations

csv='a,b,c'
combinations(csv.split(','),2)

#[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

Bibhav beat me to posting, though their answer with permutations allows duplications, e.g. '('a','b'),('b','a') whereas combinations does not. Up to your use case which is preferred.